# How to implement different ocelot.json for every microservices in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, microservices, ocelot

I am new to `microservices` architecture and already implemented micro services and API Gateway with single `ocelot.json` file as shown in below image.

[image: Project structure]

You can see there is one `ocelot.json` file in `Gateway.WebApi` project which contains routes.

Which one is better option to handle this?

1. single `ocelot.json` for all microservices
2. single `ocelot.json` for each microservice

Can we do something like we have single `ocelot.json` for each micro service?

Comment: The question is unclear. Whatever ocelot is, why can't it work with multiple settings files? What *is* `ocelot.json`? And what's *your* problem? The question is full of marketing terms (microservices architecture, API Gateway, all microservices`) that are information-free. *Every* microservice is a service, and since you used the ASP.NET Tag, an HTTP endpoint. Perhaps you created 40 separate projects for 40 endpoints? 1 project with 40 controllers? 5 projects with 4 minimal APIs each?

Comment: You may be asking how to use the same JSON file across multiple independent services - store it in one location and load it from all files. Or you may be asking how to use multiple files in the same service.

Comment: Wait, were you trying to add the entire [Implement API Gateways with Ocelot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot) book chapter to your application? The chapter warns at the very top that Envoy is used in the sample application now and even says the JSON schema changed. Besides, this only shows you how to use API gateways, it doesn't say you *should* do so. And it doesn't show one gateway per service either.

Comment: Hey I before I make an answer I want to ensure to understand you question right. You want to specify one ocelot.json and use this one ocelot.json in different container? So you wont to specify it as like a ConfigMap in e.g. Kubernetes and mount it into your containers?

Comment: If the question is about using the same file in multiple *containers*, the same file can be *mapped* to those containers as a local path

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - you are right, but what I want to do is, making separate `ocelot.json` for each microservice so, it can be manageable easily.

Comment: That comment is as unclear as the question. If you want multiple files, why not copy that file into each project or container? That requires *more* management, not less. Mapping hides where the file comes from though, making it easier to change files without actually modifying the container, only the mapping.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Question is now edited to clear you something that I am not using docker in this project as shown in the documentation of API Gateways with Ocelot

Comment: Tthis increases my suspicion that Ocelot is used without reason. How many services are in the `Microservices` folder? And since there's only *one* Gateway project, why would you need *multiple* configuration files?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP has a point if you have many microservices and if you are micromanaging the routes (not using any wildcards) a single json file may go out of range of maintainability.

Comment: In this case though it looks like there aren't many services. The JSON file is just a JSON file anyway, it can be split into multiple files or sources. The ASP.NET Core Configuration middleware will merge all the sources. The docs show that `ocelot.json` is added with `AddJson`, the same as any other JSON settings file. It only exists to keep those settings outside appsettings.json.

Comment: It also means that specific settings can be overridden by environment variables or the command line, which is very useful in a container/Kubernetes environment

Comment: It seems ocelot already provides the functionality which is mentioned [here](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html#merging-configuration-files). All you need to name your json files according to the ocelot convention.

Comment: @Eldar that's just ASP.NET Configuration code, not specific to Ocelot at all. That's what I've been writing about in the comments. If anything, the docs are buggy because the `appsettings.json` files are *already* configured.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what I mean `.AddOcelot(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment)` and  `.AddOcelot("/foo/bar", hostingContext.HostingEnvironment)` these are specific to Ocelot and merge the configuration files into one. It does similar things to my first comment.